# Rewrite history, eliminate two commit with delete and re-add

Tags: svn

Suppose I have the following tree in trunk:

```
app
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3
```

Unfortunately in a commit I accidentally deleted the `app` folder, so that commit contains one change, but removed my whole code. I re-uploaded them in a next commit, which has 3 changes, adding the 3 files and the folder. I already committed after this re-adding.

I did not loose code, but this way a I lost the history for these files before the delete commit. Is there any way to eliminate those two commits somehow so I can get back the history for these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to remove commits from a repository using a dump/edit/load process, but I think a simpler method is just to branch from the earlier revision.

- Say you had revision 15
- then you deleted app (r16)
- then you added and committed app again (r17)

So what you can do is

- svn del ^/trunk/app
- svn cp ^/trunk/app@15 ^/trunk/app

Now your app directory is restored, with history.  The only downside is that the copy means that you must disable `--stop-on-copy` when viewing the logs to see further in the past.  I used this same method once when I accidentally deleted a release branch.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunetaly i already had to push some commits since the re-adding. How can i add them after rebranching?

Comment: You should be able to merge those commits with the (-c) option from the old to the new.  svn merge -c 25 ^trunk/app@25, although you might have to add --force

Comment: The copy is working, but merging the new commit is not. I'm getting this error message `svn: E155010: The node 'D:\Csabi\Work\Biodiversity\app\^trunk\app' was not found.` I'm using a correct revision number.

Comment: If you can't get the merge to work, you can create a patch using svn diff and apply the changes manually.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i did.